# Detect any referring site info after meta refresh, http_referer stripped

Tags: meta-tags, redirect, http-referer

I own a site where emails are sent out to members that contain a link that when clicked the member receives a reward.

I am trying to find a method to block an automated browser-based application that is designed to automate the clicking of these links.

Of course the first thought is to use the HTTP_REFERER, which I know is unreliable in the first place, however, the bad site is using a meta-refresh to redirect to my link, at which time I assume the referer gets stripped.

The bad site opens a php page that simply takes the url to my site as GET data and then that data, the url to my site, is placed into a meta-refresh tag at which time the new page is redirected to my site's url.

Example link:
http:// badsite .com/frame.php?url=http:// mysite .com

Then the content of that page before the redirect contains:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http:// mysite .com">
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Is there any way I can get any refering site data at all outside of the stripped http_referer so I can detect my site being opened by the bad site so I can just kill any clicks that come from that site?

Comment: Anything normally done by the browser can be emulated by a script.

Comment: This 'bad site' is completely browser based through a TLD. I need to get something, anything, that I can identify when clicks are coming from the domain of the bad site.